# Modify contents of contenteditable div on a facebook/twitter post like grammarly

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am trying to make an extension like Grammarly. When I want to make it work on Facebook and Twitter post field it doesn't work. When I write something in the Facebook post field and want to replace a suggestion of an existing wrong word by DOM modification using javascript, replacing suggestion does occur nicely. But after that no key including backspace, delete seems to stop working. This happens only in the case of Facebook and Twitter. I wonder how Grammarly manage this. Can anyone show me the path to solve this?

`Hint:` Just open the browser post dialog and hit below that code from the browser the dev console tool to regenerate that issue.

```js
document.activeElement.innerText="hello, world"
```

**Similar Userful References**

- [Reference01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/javascript-get-clipboard-data-on-paste-event-cross-browser)
- [Reference02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260257/modify-contents-of-editable-div-on-twitter-post)
- [Reference03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040897/programmatically-change-input-value-in-facebooks-editable-div-input-area)
- [Reference04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660291/chrome-extension-doesnt-work-properly-on-facebook)

Comment: Did you find solution? I have same problem.

Comment: Yes, it solve my issue after 6 month looping